# Left brace on matrix in Xaringan

Tags: xaringan

Can we also do the following expression in Xaringan, in particular **left** brace?
I borrow the idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164664/how-to-create-an-array-with-both-vertical-and-horizontal-braces-around-the-eleme.
There might be some package limit in xaringan, but it would be great if this can be possible with Xaringan.

[image]

Comment: You cannot make use of latex expression in `xaringan`.